# How to catch missing elements in xml validation with xsd from DataSet

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

Ok, so I'm trying to validate a xml against a DataSet that represents properties for my project.
The schema addition is done like this:

```
dataSet d = new dataSet();
schema.add("http://tempuri.org/settings.xsd", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(d.GetXmlSchema())));
```

Let's say my DataSet has two Columns "path" and "version". Then if I try to validate a xml:

```
<settings>
  <paht>c:\</path>
</settings>
```

That will validate fine. And I don't want it to...  I wan't to get an error since there is no "version" entry. So I have looked at what I get from the d.GetXmlSchema() and it looks like a xsd. And all entries contains a property: `minOccurs="0"`

I'm guessing that I wan't that to be `="1"` but how do I set such an option to the DataSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this solves the problem, but it's not a nice solution...

So what we need is `"minOccurs="1"` but what we have is `...="0"` so we just do a replace at the string we get from the xml and tada!

```
dataSet d = new dataSet();
schema.add("http://tempuri.org/settings.xsd", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(d.GetXmlSchema().replace("minOccurs=\"0\"", "minOccurs=\"1\""))));
```

As I said, not that nice, if you have better suggestions please feel free to add in.